# mysql dynamic pivot table (value+value2) java error

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to get ResultSet values from dynamic pivot table:

```
SELECT nomeEscola,
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2012', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2012',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2014', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2014',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2013', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2013'
FROM temp_graph2
GROUP BY nomeEscola
```

Result:

```
nomeEscola  2012    2014    2013
xxxxx   0,027   {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  0,109   {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,333
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,222
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,083
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,3
```

Being dynamic the tables i'm assuming the object will be not recognized, then i'm using the structure to get values:

```
for...
Object value = rstSet.getObject(i);
record.add(value);
```

For String is working fine, but for "double" value is retuning null. Any Idea?

Comment: Did you try `rstSet.getDouble("2012")`, etc, i.e. using the column labels, not the index?

Comment: Yes, i tried. But not ok!

Comment: Is the actual problem in the query, i.e. do you mean that you don't want any of the values in the result set to contain nulls?

Comment: No the problem when i try to get result of (2012, 2013, 2014) that is a sum value, when i pass a value alone, for example 'APROVADO' i can get the result, but when i try to set a sum (Aprovado+Reprovado) the return for the value is null;